# Conflict occurred attempting to store application_credential - Duplicate entry found with name monitoring

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-horizon, openstack-heat, credential-manager

As i am trying to obtain application credentials on OpenStack using the following command:

```
openstack application credential create monitoring --unrestricted
```

i get an error that says:

```
Conflict occurred attempting to store application_credential - Duplicate entry found with name monitoring
```

Does it mean that credentials are already obtained and i can't create them again ?

I would really appreciate any kind of help. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

```
##general la lista de usuario y luego elimina de la lista 
[root@controller ~]# openstack user list

[root@controller ~]# openstack user list
+----------------------------------+-----------+
| ID                               | Name      |
+----------------------------------+-----------+
| 35a9a277ae71428bb750fe7325d831b0 | admin     |
| d22c71d930dc4a959ceff863ccb43cec | demo      |
| e2f3a48634434958a3f0e58fd5438cea | glance    |
| 32bcb7e060114ead8c4e92fc5ffcb60c | demo2     |
| 19b7cb2a14df43e59340336605311096 | placement |
| 49cf4ef00b7c464db6f62ccbac485cb3 | nova      |
| e8d2abfd4fad4631b0093690c07f8a50 | nova1     |
+----------------------------------+-----------+

### a usuario me refiero escribe el ID del user list que quieres elimnar
[root@controller ~]# user delete e8d2abfd4fad4631b0093690c07f8a50
[root@controller ~]# openstack user list

pagina :
https://blog.csdn.net/qq_34259391/article/details/108224730
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).